# Why is switch statement implemented the way it is in most languages?

Tags: switch-statement

pseudo code

```
int i=10

switch(i)
  case 1:
     print(1);
  case 10:
     print(10);
  case 20:
     print(20);
```

Intuitively this would be expected to print 10. But because of absence of break statement, this will print 10 and 20.

Does anyone else think this feels like an error in the language?

Comment: No, the fall-through cases can be helpful, although they're often abused. Make sure your not conflating pattern matching `switch`s, and `switch`s that match on literals.

Answer (score 2):

Not every language allows fall-through in `switch` statement. Wikipedia has a [brief section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough) on it.

- The C (C, C++, Objective-C) family allows fall through by default
- The Pascal family does not
- Perl does not by default but you can ask by for it by including `continue` keyword
- C# (which is closer to Java than C) requires a `break` to end every `case` block but allow you to group empty blocks together:
- Swift does not allow fall through and has a powerful pattern-matching system, in addition to requiring the `switch` to be exhaustive.

There's wide variety of requirements on the `switch` statements. Not every language is the same! A couple small examples:

```
// C#
switch (i) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        // you can group empty case blocks together
        break;      // but must end with break
    case 3:
        // do something else
        break;
}

// Swift
switch i {
    case 1:         // match 1
    case 2,3:       // match 2 or 3
    case 4...10:    // match 4 to 10 (inclusive)
    case let n where n % 2 == 0: // match an even number and assign it to n
    default:        // must be exhaustive
}
```

See also: [Appropriate uses of fall-through switch statements](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/116221/appropriate-uses-of-fall-through-switch-statements)